# Shapefile of England, excluding London

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, data, gadm

I originally asked this on Stack Overflow, but here was suggested as a better location.

Where could I get a shapefile (or even better an R spatial polygon data frame) of the boundary of England, where London is a boundary and the London area is not part of the shape (essentially a really really weird doughnut...see below) or is there a way to create it myself (using GIS excluded!)?

[image]

Comment: This would be easy to create with GIS; why is using GIS excluded?

Comment: I don't have access to GIS unfortunately!

Comment: QGIS is an open-source 'free' GIS http://qgis.org/en/site/ available for linux, windows and Mac OS X

Comment: Using something like PostGIS to select outside a circle, bounding box, or other shape all polygons, you can get fairly close. To get more accurate, you need to use code and something like a defined set of boundaries to rip out London.  After that, there are plenty of basics to convert PostGIS or other formats to a shapefile even if they involve a step or two.

Comment: @Mapperz why "free"? It's just free...

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this in R by downloading the Level 2 boundary data for the UK from [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/download) and choosing the option to download the R SpatialDataPolygonsDataFrame (`.rds` file).

In R:

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

##read in the RData file
uk_gadm <- readRDS('GBR_adm2.rds')

##Filter the dataset to exclude London Borough and only include England 
uk_gadm_lesslondon <- uk_gadm[!grepl( 'London Borough*', uk_gadm$ENGTYPE_2) & uk_gadm$NAME_1 == 'England',]

##plot the output
plot(uk_gadm_lesslondon, col='red')
```

[image]

You can then dissolve the polygons using the approach included by radouxju or as follows:

```
uk_diss <- unionSpatialPolygons(uk_gadm_lesslondon, uk_gadm_lesslondon$ID_1, avoidGEOS=TRUE)

 plot(uk_diss, col='cyan')
```

[image]

Comment: and after selecting, go for https://philmikejones.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/dissolve-polygons-in-r/ Very similar to what you want !

Comment: Awesome, that's me @radouxju ! I've moved to http://philmikejones.me/2015/09/03/dissolve-polygons-in-r/

Comment: You can use `png` to save the plots instead of using screen caps